# How does Dempster-Shafer Theory of Evidence relate to Deep Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, bayesian

I am reading [this](https://nn.labml.ai/uncertainty/evidence/index.html#:%7E:text=This%20corresponds%20to%20a%20Dirichlet,known%20as%20the%20Dirichlet%20strength.) article and it has the following phrase - *"Dempster-Shafer Theory of Evidence assigns belief masses a set of classes (unlike assigning a probability to a single class)*". However, I am not able to understand this concept. Why would one typically assign a probability to a class in the first place. Also, why is Dempster-Shafer's technique better? Finally, why does the sum of belief masses and uncertainty sum to 1?

Based on my [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory), this is what D-S Theory does - "In this formalism a degree of belief (also referred to as a mass) is represented as a belief function rather than a Bayesian probability distribution.". I also read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365679/how-does-dempster-shafer-relate-to-machine-learning) article but it didn't help me.